# Android Studio launching app gets stuck infinitely

Tags: java, android

I just recently installed Android Studio and any time I click 'Run app' button it will load infinitely before timing out. The emulator is launched and runs fine, but the Background Tasks always shows either "Terminating App" or "Waiting for all target devices to come online".

The Gradle does build successfully, but after that I just get the infinite launching until timeout.
I also get a "App failed to install" message after this timeout.

[Waiting for target devices: Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s85N.png)

[Terminating App: Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2JoX.png)

I'd be happy to give any more necessary information, I really need to get this fixed for my Mobile App Development class.

Android Studio Version: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1

I've tried everything I can think of, invalidating the cache, restarting my device and Android Studio, reinstalling. I can't even seem to find any error logs so I haven't been able to diagnose this issue myself.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar.  I think I had `adb` installed via brew.

For me

```
brew  uninstall android-platform-tools
```

fixed the issue

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I didn't install via Brew. It's happening after Giraffe and very frequently. The only solution is to kill adb manually from activity monitor (Task Manager) and re-run the app.